# Go smtp send email

Tags: email, go

I am trying to send an email using Go. However I try to use my host custom mail servers which are the followings

[image]

So I am not quite sure what should I use over here. I am doing the following

```
auth := smtp.PlainAuth("", "noreply@icon-universe.com", "password", "mail.icon-universe.com")
log.Println(smtp.SendMail("mail.icon-universe.com:25", auth, "noreply@icon-universe.com", []string{"to@gmail.com"}, []byte("This is a simple test")))
```

However this would give me the following error

> x509: certificate is valid for server.premierehost.net,
> [www.server.premierehost.net](http://www.server.premierehost.net), not mail.icon-universe.com

So then I tried the following

```
auth := smtp.PlainAuth("", "noreply@icon-universe.com", "password", "server.premierehost.net")
log.Println(smtp.SendMail("server.premierehost.net:465", auth, "noreply@icon-universe.com", []string{"nakotoffana@gmail.com"}, []byte("thanks for loggin in")))
```

However this would just make my app go on an infinite loop...

Which connection details should I use?

---

Update

I decided to try go-mail and seems to work but not for @gmail

```
d := gomail.NewDialer("server.premierehost.net", 465, "noreply@icon-universe.com", "password")
m := gomail.NewMessage()
m.SetHeader("From", "noreply@icon-universe.com")
m.SetHeader("To", "carvajal@karmagameworks.com")
m.SetHeader("Subject", "Hello!")
m.SetBody("text/html", "Hello <b>Bob</b> and <i>Cora</i>!")
log.Println(d.DialAndSend(m))
```

This will work and the email will appear but sending to @gmail.com won't (the email will never arrive)

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be using gomail correctly, but you should make sure the email account on gmail you are trying to send from has less secure apps turned on, otherwise this will never actually send.

Answer (score 0):

firstly less secure apps must be turned on for your gmail account.

After that go to *security section* of your gmail account and in *signing in google* part, add a new app (create).
Then google will give a new app pass for that account.
Use that app password as your password

it will work